# SVG and dynamic resizing - vuejs

Tags: vue.js, svg, size, scaling

I am pulling hair from my head for weeks already.

I can't figure out how to deal with SVG files.
Essentially I want to have all my svg icons as components in vue, so I started converting them to components.
Here is an example of svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M.75 10.5A.749.749 0 010 9.75v-7.5a.749.749 0 01.75-.75h6a.749.749 0 01.75.75.75.75 0 01-.75.75H1.5v6h6V6.75A.75.75 0 018.25 6a.75.75 0 01.75.75v3a.75.75 0 01-.75.75zm3.97-3.22a.75.75 0 010-1.06l4.5-4.5a.727.727 0 01.08-.053L8.379.746A.437.437 0 018.687 0h2.876A.437.437 0 0112 .437v2.876a.436.436 0 01-.745.308l-.921-.921a.588.588 0 01-.053.08l-4.5 4.5a.749.749 0 01-.531.22.749.749 0 01-.531-.22z"/>
</svg>
```

Now I was thinking to wrap it something like this:

```js
<template>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    viewBox="0 0 18 18"
    :aria-labelledby="iconName"
    role="presentation"
  >
    <title
      :id="iconName"
      lang="en"
    >{{ iconName }} icon</title>
    <g :fill="iconColor">
      <slot/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</template>
```

But no matter what I do it does not resize, I tried to change `viewBox` to `0 0 100 100` or dynamic with `0 0 width height`, with last one it does change but in not the way I understand it.

Also I struggled to make path to fill svg container, so if I change width and height svg is always bigger than path which also is not nice behavior. The only way I managed to be the size I want (but not dynamic) is by adding `transform="scale(1.34,1.34)"`  to path, but that's not a fix.

What is the best way to create icons like that ? I fried my brain.

Comment: Try removing the width and the height of the svg element.

Comment: but then what? how can I resize it ?

Comment: An svg element without a width and height will take all the available width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to ensure the SVG files are created or exported nicely from whatever program (Figma, Illustrator, etc) to ensure there's no excess whitespace from the artboard included in the SVG. The SVG code provided looks like the SVG was placed on an artboard which was much larger than the graphic itself.

Beyond that, I manually experimented with the viewBox numbers to get a decent result (correct exporting avoids this manual work). Once the viewBox attributes are correctly set, you can apply other manipulations via classes or inline css to achieve your desired result.

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 12 11" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M.75 10.5A.749.749 0 010 9.75v-7.5a.749.749 0 01.75-.75h6a.749.749 0 01.75.75.75.75 0 01-.75.75H1.5v6h6V6.75A.75.75 0 018.25 6a.75.75 0 01.75.75v3a.75.75 0 01-.75.75zm3.97-3.22a.75.75 0 010-1.06l4.5-4.5a.727.727 0 01.08-.053L8.379.746A.437.437 0 018.687 0h2.876A.437.437 0 0112 .437v2.876a.436.436 0 01-.745.308l-.921-.921a.588.588 0 01-.053.08l-4.5 4.5a.749.749 0 01-.531.22.749.749 0 01-.531-.22z"/>
</svg>
```

I would recommend using class or style binding for hooking up any css styles in Vue, the docs cover this here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Demo with plain SVG and Vue versions: https://codepen.io/nikcornish/pen/OJXoWvj

Comment: Awesome, thank you I think now I understand how it works! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to change the size of the icon itself right?

If so, the width and the height attributes won't do anything for you. You can just apply regular css to your svg for that matter.

example:

```
.my-svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Regarding the viewBox attribute, that is a different concept:

> The viewBox attribute defines the position and dimension, in user
> space, of an SVG viewport.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

EDIT:
Please note that you can also use [svg-to-vue-component](https://github.com/egoist/svg-to-vue-component) to use SVGs as components.